# How to do Json to Json transformation in Java

Tags: json, transformation

What are some of the best & most efficient JSON to JSON transformation libraries?
Need not be open source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By `JSON to JSON transformation`, do you mean JSON to java object and vice-versa?

Comment: no. I mean converting JsonA to JsonB. Looking for something like [link]https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt library. But an enterprise one.